# Limit of sequence. with Factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, factorial

Can't find the limit of this sequence :
$$\frac{3^n(2n)!}{n!(2n)^n}$$
tried to solve this using the ratio test buy failed... 
need little help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's the problem with the ratio test?:

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)!\color{red}{3^{n+1}}}{(n+1)!(\color{green}{2}(n+1))^{n+1}}\frac{n!(\color{green}{2}n)^n}{(2n)!\color{red}{3^n}}=\frac{(2n+1)\cdot3}{n+1}\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac6e>1$$

and thus...

Comment: I believe the excess factor of  2  should be in the denominator, where, together with the excess factor of  $ \ (n+1) \ $, the factor of $ \ (2n+2) \ $ was cancelled.  The only factors remaining are the $ \ 3 \ $ , the $ \ \( \frac{2n+1}{n+1} \)  \ $ , and the $ \ \( \frac{n}{n+1} \)^n \ $  .  This doesn't alter the conclusion materially...

Comment: You are right, of course. Editing on its way and thanks, @RecklessReckoner .

Comment: OK, and I spotted a correction to my remark that I also had to fix...

Comment: yes I agree with @RecklessReckoner and I got it thank you both

Answer (score 1):

As tenpercent said,
since
$n!
\sim \sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n$,

$\begin{align}
\frac{3^n(2n)!}{n!(2n)^n}
&\sim \frac{3^n\sqrt{2\pi 2n} (2n/e)^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n} (n/e)^n(2n)^n}\\
&= \frac{3^n2^{2n}n^{2n}\sqrt{4\pi n} /e^{2n}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}2^n n^{2n}/e^n}\\
&= \frac{3^n2^{n}\sqrt{2} }{e^n}\\
&=\left( \frac{6}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2}
\end{align}
$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use Stirling formula, $n! \simeq \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$

Comment: I used ratio test succeeded with it.
But I'm curios is it official to use Stirling in calculus solving a limit ?

Comment: @user1993748 , why not?

Comment: Once one finishes an introductory course in calculus I think any higher level theorems can be used anywhere. If a professor has an objection in an exam it should be clearly spelt out during the exam. I however object to such high level techniques in an introductory course because they tend to distract focus from simple and fundamental concepts. On the other hand if a question can be solved by simpler technique then its definitely better (like the current question which is easily handled by ratio test).